# Perform comparison on a function's generic return type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get information about the generic type passed to a function or class, so that I can perform some logic on it somewhere else. I want specific behavior depending on the return type of the function, but I have no clue how to check this.

Suppose I have this simple object:

```
interface MyObj<T> {
  fn: (obj: T) => T;
}
const obj: MyObj<number> = { fn: (obj: number): number => 4 };
```

I can get the return type by doing:

type myType = ReturnType;

I would then like to be able to do:

```
if (myType === "number") { // 'myType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. ts(2693)
  doSomething();
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.

Your `myType` is a type annotation which is used by the type-checker at compile time. It is then "compiled away" and does not exist at runtime. Therefor you cannot do a runtime check against it.

You can do a runtime type assertion against a concrete value.

```
const value = obj.fn(0); 

if (typeof value === 'number') {
  doSometing(); 
}
```